# Css attribute without last child

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a grey lines that will separated red divs, the final result should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEbrc.png)

I have a problem with eliminate the line after last red div, my code is:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            .authorsContainer{
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;     
            }
            
            .authorIconVisibility, .authorName{
                float:left;
            }
            
            .booksContainer{
                display: flex;
                clear: both;
            }
            
            .bookContainer{
                float: left;
                flex: 1;
            }
            
            .bookInfo{
                position: relative;
                background: green;
            }
            
            .bookInfo:after{
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                background: #ccc;
                height: 2px;
                left: 25%;
                right: 25%;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
            
            .bookName, .bookYear{
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            .bookDescription{
                position: relative;
                background: red;
                min-height: 100px;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            
            .bookDescription:after{
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                background: #ccc;
                width: 2px;
                top: 25%;
                bottom: 25%;
                right: -10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="authorsContainer">
            <div class="authorContainer">
                <div class="authorInfo">
                    <div class="authorIconVisibility">icon</div>
                    <div class="authorName">name</div>
                </div>          
                <div class="booksContainer">                
                    <div class="bookContainer">
                        <div class="bookInfo">
                            <div class="bookName">n1</div>
                            <div class="bookYear">y1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bookDescription">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="bookContainer">
                        <div class="bookInfo">
                            <div class="bookName">n2</div>
                            <div class="bookYear">y2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bookDescription">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="bookContainer">
                        <div class="bookInfo">
                            <div class="bookName">n3</div>
                            <div class="bookYear">y3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bookDescription">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the last css selector to

```
.bookContainer .bookDescription:not(:last-child):after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #111;
    width: 2px;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    right: -10px;
}
```

but it does not work (there is no lines at all).

What should I change?

Comment: .bookContainer:last-child .bookDescription:after {all: initial}

Comment: @VXp u are totally right!  changed that for non child and it works! thank u very much

Comment: No probs, glad it does.